# If $p$ and $q$ are prime ideals in a ring such that $p\subsetneq q$ is ht$(p)<$ht$(q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If we have a containment of prime ideals in a  commutative ring with $1$ is the "larger" prime ideal necessarily of the higher height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember, the height of a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is equal to the number of strict inclusions in a maximal chain of primes ending in $\mathfrak{p}$. So, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is strictly contained in $\mathfrak{q}$, then a maximal chain of primes ending in $\mathfrak{q}$ must necessarily have more inclusions - so, yes (provided that we are in a Noetherian ring, thus there are no infinite chains of prime ideals).

Let $\mathfrak{p}_0 \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_1 \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_n = \mathfrak{p}$ be a maximal chain of primes with respect to inclusion (so that $ht(\mathfrak{p})=n$), then this chain can be extended to $\mathfrak{p}_0 \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_1 \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_n \subsetneq \mathfrak{q}$, which has one more inclusion than the original chain. Since $ht(\mathfrak{q})$ depends on the *maximum* length of a chain of primes, it may only increase from $n+1$ (since perhaps our extended chain is not of maximal length).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't see why a maximal chain containing $q$ must have more inclusions. It's not necessary that such a chain will contain $p$. So it seems like it's possible we have two different chains one terminating at $p$ and another at $q$ such that the second one does not contain $p$ and have the same lengths.

Comment: But height depends on a _maximal_ chain - so we certainly have a chain of primes that is longer when we end with $\mathfrak{q}$ (the chain that contains $\mathfrak{p}$) as opposed to ending with $\mathfrak{p}$, so creating a shorter chain is irrelevant.

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify regarding my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks. I got confused between height of an ideal being the infimum of the heights of the primes containing it and height of a prime ideal. I was assuming it is the length of the smallest chain.

Comment: Although, we should say longest or maximum length chain and not maximal.

Comment: Yeah, I got lazy with that last parenthetical... previous mentions were more specific. Edited to reflect your comment. And indeed, the height of an ideal $I$ being the infimum of heights of primes containing $I$ does get a little confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Without restricting to finite heights, the answer is no; we could have $\mathfrak{p}\subsetneq\mathfrak{q}$ but $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p})=\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{q})=\infty$. For example, in $R=\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$, the polynomial ring in infinitely many variables over $\mathbb{C}$, the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}=(x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ is strictly contained inside $\mathfrak{q}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$, but both $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ contain infinitely long chains of strict inclusions of prime ideals, e.g.

$$\mathfrak{q}\supsetneq\mathfrak{p}\supsetneq(x_3,x_4,\ldots)\supsetneq(x_4,x_5,\ldots)\supsetneq\cdots$$

so $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{p})=\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{q})=\infty$.

Comment: We always have $\mathrm{ht}(q)\ge \mathrm{ht}(p)+\mathrm{ht}(q/p)$. If $p\ne q$, then $\mathrm{ht}(q/p)>0.$

Comment: Agreed - though if $p$ and $q$ are both of infinite height, this is not a contradiction; or am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. What I meant is even when $p, q$ have infinite height, one can say $q$ has bigger height than $p$ because $q/p$ has positive height.